# regex for negation of ends with matching

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I need a regex to match strings that do not end in certain terms.

Input is a bunch of Class names, like `Foo`, `FooImpl`, `FooTest`, `FooTestSuite`, etc.

I want to match anything that does not end in `Test`, `Tests`, or `TestSuite`.

Should Match:

- `FooImpl`
- `FooTestImpl`
- `Foo`

Should not match:

- `FooTest`
- `FooTestSuite`
- `FooTests`

I just can't get this right. What I have now is wrong so I won't even bother posting it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try a negative lookbehind if your language supports it:

```
/(?<!Test)(<?!Tests)(<?!TestSuite)$/
```

Otherwise you can simulate a negative lookbehind using a negative lookahead:

```
/^(?!.*(?:Test|Tests|TestSuite)$).*$/
```

[Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/lGwNipAiNI)

Comment: Rewrite the variable-length negative look behind so it works more places than one: `/(?<!TestSuite)(?<!Tests)(?<!Test)$/`.

Answer (score 1):

Negative matching is something regex can't actually do for the most part. Is there some reason you can just do !(string =~ regex)?

That's why grep has a -v (invert match) flag.

Comment: +1: Agree with don't match for nonexistence, but rather match for existence and invert the match. Far easier.

Answer (score 0):

I propose an alternative solution using grep:

`grep -vE ".+(Test|Tests|TestSuite)$" *`

`-v` is negation, `-E` is for regex matching. Since not all languages support lookaheads and lookbehinds and grep is mostly platform independent, it could be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using a word boundary operator:

```
test\b|tests\b|testSuite\b
```

That will target words that end with those characters.